# Javascript, Multiselect copy to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, copy, textarea

I want to copy multiselect options to textarea. I wrote code and it goes well up till I change value in textarea box for example when I add something. After adding additionaly characters to textarea JS coping function don't work. Why? This is code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<form class="form multiple-select-form form-move">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1-2">Multiselect:<br/>
            <select id="source_select" multiple="multiple" style="width: 500px; height:200px">
                <option value="option 1"> option 1 </option>
                <option value="option 2"> option 2 </option>
                <option value="option 3"> option 3 </option>
                <option value="option 4"> option 4 </option>
                <option value="option 5"> option 5 </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-2"><br/><br/>Textarea:<br/>
            <textarea name="text_to_db" id="target_textarea"  style="width: 500px; height:200px"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1-1"><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Copy multiselect to textarea</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
            if (document.getElementById("source_select").length > 0) {
                for (let i=0; i < document.getElementById("source_select").length; i++){
                    const option = document.getElementById("source_select").options[i];
                    const value = option.value;
                    if (option.selected) {
                        let nowy_tekst = document.getElementById("target_textarea").innerHTML + value + ", ";
                        document.getElementById("target_textarea").innerHTML = nowy_tekst;
                       // option.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` since `textarea` is a form element.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<form class="form multiple-select-form form-move">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1-2">Multiselect:<br/>
            <select id="source_select" multiple="multiple" style="width: 500px; height:200px">
                <option value="option 1"> option 1 </option>
                <option value="option 2"> option 2 </option>
                <option value="option 3"> option 3 </option>
                <option value="option 4"> option 4 </option>
                <option value="option 5"> option 5 </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-2"><br/><br/>Textarea:<br/>
            <textarea name="text_to_db" id="target_textarea"  style="width: 500px; height:200px"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1-1"><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Copy multiselect to textarea</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
            if (document.getElementById("source_select").length > 0) {
                for (let i=0; i < document.getElementById("source_select").length; i++){
                    const option = document.getElementById("source_select").options[i];
                    const value = option.value;
                    if (option.selected) {
                        let nowy_tekst = document.getElementById("target_textarea").value + value + ", ";
                        document.getElementById("target_textarea").value = nowy_tekst;
                       // option.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lots :) now it works properly

Comment: Good! Would be nice if you mark answer as accepted with check on it's left :)

Comment: of coures. i newbe here so thanks for instructions